# Typescript: Define the return of key value of an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a method called `getSpecificPlacementOption` and I wanted to define its return value. Unfortunately i'm quite new to Typescript so i'm not sure how to define it. I have an object called `placementOptions` and what I want to return is the specific value of one of it's specific keys:

```
export interface PlacementOptions {
  badgeOptions?: BadgeOptions;
  cardLayoutOptions?: CardLayoutOptions;
}

const getSpecificPlacementOption = (key: placementOptionsKey) => placementOptions[key];
```

How do I define the return of this method `placementOptions[key]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Return type could instead be inferred
function getSpecificPlacementOption<T extends keyof PlacementOptions>(key: T): PlacementOptions[T] {
  return placementOptions[key];
}

const getSpecificPlacementOption2: <T extends keyof PlacementOptions>(key: T) => PlacementOptions[T]
  = key => placementOptions[key];
```

Simpler, but TypeScript doesn't know which property is being returned, only that some is:

```
const getSpecificPlacementOption =
    (key: keyof PlacementOptions) => placementOptions[key];
```

Comment: What if I defined `key` as `PlacementOptionsKey`. How would that look like replacing `T`?

Comment: `type PlacementOptionsKey = keyof PlacementOptions` would just replace `keyof PlacementOptions` in the above type definitions. You wouldn't get the generic return type as with `<T extends keyof PlacementOptions>` and `PlacementOptions[T]`.